# Double gang outlets with more than four outlets

Tags: electrical, receptacle

I can find adapters for single gang outlets with up to six receptacles.  However, I can't find any way to get more than four outlets in my double gang outlets.  Does anything like this exist.  My wife needs more outlets in our bathroom.

Answer (score 2):

Use a "surface conduit starter box" on top of the 2-gang box.
Something like Legrand Wiremold will suffice.

Then, run surface conduits to any number of new receptacle locations.

Answer (score 1):

As I recall outlet strips are officially not for permanent installation -- which may cause one to question why they're made with mounting holes on the back side that make them easy to mount to the side of a vanity as below.

[image]

Comment: Asking why a "temporary use only" power strip has mounting holes is like asking why the sky is blue...

Answer (score 0):

To get more receptacles you could use short splitter cords: [https://www.amazon.com/Cablelera-Power-Extension-Splitter-ZWACPQAG-14/dp/B00FRODUR4/ref=asc_df_B00FRODUR4/?tag=hyprod-20&linkCode=df0&hvadid=309881068962&hvpos=&hvnetw=g&hvrand=17653962339055661662&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=t&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9026945&hvtargid=pla-450496566643&psc=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00FRODUR4)

Answer (score 0):

There are a LOT of variations of these (some even have USB ports!):

[image]

Just make sure the ground fault interrupt is enabled for every outlet in the bathroom.